# Referencing to `this` child from parent context

Tags: c#, inheritance, reference

I have a `Parent` class that has few children. I'd like each of those children to write it's construction to a shared log. my log has a method `log_my_creation(object)` that actually uses the calling object's type. If I'd call `log_my_creation(this)` from `Parent` constructor, I'd obviously get  the type of `Parent` instead of a specific child, meanwhile I call `log_my_creation(this)` from each child's constructor individually, which feels kinda wrong.

**My Question is**: how can I refer to this as the child it is, though in a method of parent.

Clarification code:

Now:

```
class Parent{}

class Child_1
{
 public Child1()
 {
  log.log_my_creation(this);
 }
}
```

Wishful desire (following code will of course won't due) :

```
class Parent
{
 public Parent()
 {
  log.log_my_creation(this); // logs the creation of the child it is 
 }
}
```

Such that the following code:

```
Parent p = new Parent();
Child1 c1 = new Child1();
Child1 c2 = new Child2();
```

-will output (to log) the following:

```
A Parent was constructed.
A Child1 was constructed.
A Child2 was constructed.
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> If I'd call log_my_creation(this) from Parent constructor, I'd obviously get the type of Parent instead of a specific child

No, you wouldn't.

The behavior that you're asking for is the way the code will already behave.  `this` refers to the instance of the actual object, and in this case, it's runtime type will be the type of the child, not the parent, because the instance actually is that of a child class.

The compile time type of `this` will be `Parent`, in the parent constructor, but the runtime type of `this` will be of the child type actually being created.  If your log method has different overloads for different types, rather than using reflection to determine the type of the object to log, then that would be your problem.  Change the logger to look at the runtime type, not the compile time type (or provide an additional method that has that behavior).

Comment: right in the childhood :) . this is great actually, I guess there always a chance that things are just the way you want them to be. I thinks I got skeptical because it was a constructor.